# Reducing Resolution using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am just starting to use GEE to do some raster preparation for ecological niche modeling. Mostly, I am using MODIS images at 1,000 m resolution so this is the scale I need for all my rasters. MODIS uses sinusoidal projection "SR-ORG:6974".

Now, in processing SRTM Digital Elevation Data Version 4, I performed raster export after selecting my export area as follows:

```
// Display DEM model
var DEM = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4')
.select('elevation')
.clip(Argentina)
print('DEM', DEM.projection().nominalScale())
print('DEM', DEM)

Map.addLayer(DEM, {}, 'DEM')

// Create export region
var ExportArea = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-73.7,-55.0,-53.4,-21.4]);
Map.addLayer(ExportArea, {color: 'FF0000'}, 'poly');

// Export raster 1
Export.image.toDrive({
image: DEM,
description: 'DEM',
folder: 'My drive folder',
crs: 'SR-ORG:6974',
maxPixels: 1e13,
scale: 1000,
region: ExportArea,});
```

I need a final raster at a resolution of 1,000 m. Although the above procedure is straightforward, I was wondering if it is the best approach to reduce resolution from 90 (DEM) to 1000 m (MODIS).

Then, following GEE developers' advice on how to aggregate pixels to larger pixels (MODIS at 1,000 m) in a different projection https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/resample I did the following:

```
// Load a MODIS EVI image.
var modis = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1').first())
    .select('EVI');
    
Map.addLayer(modis, {}, 'MODIS')
    
// Get information about the MODIS projection.
var modisProjection = modis.projection();
print('MODIS projection:', modisProjection);

// Load and display DEM data at 90 m resolution
var DEM = ee.Image('CGIAR/SRTM90_V4')
.select('elevation')

print('DEM scale', DEM.projection().nominalScale())

// Get information about the DEM projection
var DEMProjection = DEM.projection();
print('DEM projection:', DEMProjection);

// Get the DEM data at MODIS scale and projection
var DEM_reproj = DEM
    
// Force the next reprojection to aggregate instead of resampling
.reduceResolution({
reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
maxPixels: 1024
})
    
// Request the data at the scale and projection of the MODIS image
.reproject({
crs: modisProjection
});

// Create region
var ExportArea = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([-73.7,-55.0,-53.4,-21.4]);
Map.addLayer(ExportArea, {color: 'FF0000'}, 'poly');

// Export raster 2 
  Export.image.toDrive({
  image: DEM_reproj, 
  description: 'DEM',
  folder: 'WildBoar',
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  scale:1000,
  region: ExportArea,});
```

After exporting both of the above raster to My Drive, I explored them in QGIS and obtained the following information for each:

### Exported raster 1 (QGIS)

```
Extent
-73.7067690620067424,-55.4260530301744723 : 
-53.3958604880643577,-21.3978700677270020

Unit: degrees

Origin: -73.7068, -21.3979

Pixel Size: 0.00898315, -0.00898315
```

[image]

### Exported raster 2 (QGIS)

```
Extent
-7631000.0000000000000000,-6163000.0000000000000000 : 
-3405000.0000000000000000,-2379000.0000000000000000

Unit: meters

Origin: -7.631e+06, -2.379e+06

Pixel Size: 1000, -1000
```

[image]

So at this point my main question is: Which method is the correct one? As seen in the screenshots above, the first script outputs a raster with pixel size 0.00898315 by 0.00898315 degrees, which equals 997.12965 m E/W at 45° S (center of Argentina). Exported raster 2, on the other hand, consists of a raster with a 1,000 by 1,000 m pixel size. The way pixels are aligned in Output 2, however, looks odd to me, as evidence by their inclination. I am not sure what may account for this, or if this is an expected behavior at all. By the way, pixels appear tilted in GEE as well.

Comment: i think it is because the different crs.